# unit test cases for angular6 application using jasmin/kerma

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I would like to write unit test cases for below code which is written in angular6 application.

```
ngOnDestroy() : void{
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }
  scroller(page:number) {
    let scroller = document.getElementById("scroll")
    if(scroller!= null){
      scroller.scrollTop=0;
    }
  }
```

but it gives error as below:
describe('scroller', () => {

```
 it('scrollTop scrollbar', ()=>{
    // var mockedDocElement = document.createElement('div');
    // document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('scroll')
    // expect(mockedDocElement.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 0);
    spyOn(document, "getElementById").and.callFake(function() {
      return {
          value: 'scroll'
      }
  }); 
  })
})
```

but code coverage does not cover all the code, if anyone can help me on this

Comment: Is there any error message given?

Comment: No it does not cover full code

Comment: I was looking at how best we can write unit test cases for above methods/functions